# How to aggregate based on condition of a column in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
    df:
    id|flag|fee
    1 |0   |5
    1 |0   |5
    1 |1   |5
    1 |1   |5

    DESRIED df_aggregated:
    id|flag|fee
    1 |2   |10
```

The aggregate should count the number of flags per id and the fee should sum per id when the flag is set to 1:

```
df1=df.groupby(['id'])["flag"].apply(lambda x : x.astype(int).count()).reset_index()
df2=df.groupby(['id'])["fee"].apply(lambda x : x.astype(int).sum()).reset_index()
df_aggregated=pd.merge(df1, df2, on='id', how='inner')

   ACTUAL df_aggregated:
   id|flag|fee
   1 |2   |20
```

My fee aggregation is NOT correct/complete because it is not accounting for the condition of only summing the fee IF THE FLAG=1. Instead if sums up all fees regarding of the flag. How do I change my code to account for this condition? It should look like the DESIRED df_aggregated table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for the condition `flag==1`. In doing so, you can multiply `fee` with `df.flag.eq(1)`:

```
(df.assign(fee=df.fee*df.flag.eq(1))
   .groupby('id', as_index=False)
   .agg({'flag':'nunique', 'fee':'sum'})
)
```

Output:

```
   id  flag  fee
0   1     2   10
```

If you want **both** to count/sum **only** where `flag==1`, you can do a query first:

```
(df.query('flag==1')
   .groupby('id', as_index=False)
   .agg({'flag':'count', 'fee':'sum'})
)
```

which incidentally gives the same output as above.